# Alternatives to bounded root finding functions

Tags: python, scipy-optimize, minimization, economics, root-finding

My question involves a bounded root finding problem for when the
function behaves strangely when it is near zero.

### Setup

I am trying to find the root for the following equation

[image]

where

[image]

kappa, chi, theta and alpha are all parameters that I set. the
variable k is a 30 by 30 grid.

I am trying to find the root for h evaluating at all k grid points.
The root should return an h that is between the bounds 0 and 1. The
function is increasing, but in areas when h is close to zero (usually
less than 0.1) it will cross the x-axis twice. This occurs for some
grid points that I evaluate at and others it does not happen. In
theory this shouldn't happen.  So when I evaluate at grid points using
bisection methods like bisect and brentq at most grid points it works
but for some I will get an error "f(a) and f(b) positive".

So I instead trying to turn the root finding problem in a minimization
problem where I square the function and use brent function. But I am
still running into similar problems like before. However this time it
will stop because of too many iterations and many of the solutions are
not in the specified bounds.

```
for i in range(nk):
    for j in range(nk):
        def foch(n):
             return (kappa*n**chi - (kgrid[i]**(alpha)*n**(1-alpha) +
(1-delta)*kgrid[i] -
kgrid[j])**(-theta)*(1-alpha)*(kgrid[i])**(alpha)*n**(-alpha))**2
        res[i,j] =opt.brent(foch, brack=(10e-3, 1))
```

### Question

How can I find the root to this equation which in theory is unique? Is
there an alternative method that I could use than standard
root-finding or minimazation problems?

### Code

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt

##### parameters #####
beta, alpha, delta, theta,  chi = 0.988, 0.321, 0.013, 1,  0.5

#number of grid points.
nk = 30

#setting up the grid
kstar = (1/3)*(alpha/(1/beta - (1-delta)))**(1/(1 - alpha))
kmin=0.25*kstar
kmax=1.75*kstar
kgrid = np.linspace(kmin, kmax, nk)

#set ss labor hours
nstar=.2925
cstar = kstar**alpha*nstar**(1-alpha) - delta*kstar

#endogenously determine kappa
kappa=(1/nstar**chi)*cstar**(-theta)*(1-alpha)*(kstar/nstar)**alpha

#### solve ####
res=np.empty((nk, nk))

for i in range(nk):
    for j in range(nk):
        def foch(n):
             return (kappa*n**chi - (kgrid[i]**(alpha)*n**(1-alpha) +
(1-delta)*kgrid[i] -
kgrid[j])**(-theta)*(1-alpha)*(kgrid[i])**(alpha)*n**(-alpha))**2
        res[i,j] =opt.brent(foch, brack=(10e-3, 1))
```

Comment: As written, `foch` does not appear to have real roots within your bracket (0 to 1) for all `i` and `j`. For instance, plot the function within your bracket for `i=0`, `j=2`. The minimum value of the function within that interval is 3.18.